# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable for while loop with i

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to fix it. This is my code below and it is giving me three error messages, including the one above which is for the while I <=129 line.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
extracting_value = dataset.pop('F000003C')

rel_valu = []
for value in extracting_value:
  if value.find["CAFE"] >= 0:
    start_index = extracting_value.index(value)
    while i <= 129:
      i +=1
      list_value = extract_value[start_index + 2]
      rel_valu.append[list_value]
```

Comment: i think the extracting_value is not a list and is causing the error

Comment: Turn the square brackets in `rel_valu.append[..]` to normal parantheses. The "built-in function or method" it refers to is `append` method of lists.

Comment: Mustafa Aydin thank you. I tried that but I still have the same error.

Comment: Prathamesh Jadhav I can print the extracting_value and see that it is in fact a list.

Comment: There seems to be another error in the line above the one you indicated.  It should read `if value.find("CAFE") >= 0:` with round parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: Tobias than you! When I do that I get an error about the range instead: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable